# NetworkStream - wait until all bytes were physically delivered to network adapter

Tags: c#, networkstream

I use the following code to copy from a stream into a NetworkStream.
But, calling the target's Write method doesn't mean the bytes were immediately transmitted over the line.

Is there any way to wait until the bytes were sent thru the network adapter to the line?

```
 private static long CopyStream(Stream input, NetworkStream output, int bufferSize)
    {
      byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
      int count = 0;
      long total = 0;

      DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
      while ((count = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
      {
        output.Write(buffer, 0, count);
      }


      TimeSpan tselapsed = DateTime.Now - start;

      double bps = Math.Round((input.Length / tselapsed.TotalSeconds) / 1000, 2);

      Trace.WriteLine(bps + " Kbytes/sec");
      return total;
    }
```

Comment: On the line they might be delivered into a back hole. The only way to be sure is to receive a reply.

Comment: Black hole or whatever... still, is it possible???

Comment: Do you understand that what you want does not help you? Do you understand what I said?

Comment: Have you tried to Flush the stream?

Comment: Tried it.. no good : "The Flush method implements the Stream.Flush method; however, because NetworkStream is not buffered, it has no affect on network streams..." from MSDN.

Comment: Even if this were possible, it would do you no good. The network adapter/driver can itself buffer data, and that's not even considering the fact that transmitting the data takes time as well, and that's not considering the fact that the receiving network adapter needs time to receive it. TCP/IP was deliberately designed with the ability to overcome intermittent connection loss -- that's a feature, not a bug. What actual *problem* are you trying to solve -- and why wouldn't it be solved by the receiver telling you "received at timestamp X, thanks"?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, you cannot.
The reason is that you are operating at the application level using sockets. But underneeth those sockets are other layers, not to mention the socket layer itself, which implement buffers of their own. When they decide to actually put something on the wire is out of your hands and depending on the implementation of those lower layers.